# why I can't find the option "-E" in sed

Tags: shell

I see a shell like `sed -n -E '/^[0-9]{3}$/p' file.txt` to print only lines with only 3 digits in file.txt.
Why I can't find the -E option in "man sed" or "info sed"? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find it because `-E` is not a documented `sed` option. The fact is GNU `sed` [implements](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/tree/sed/sed.c#n273) it as an alias to `-r` (use extended regular expressions) and acts accordingly.

```
$ date | sed -E 's/0/x/g'
Thu Apr  9 1x:54:14 CEST 2x15
```

A most orthodox `sed` implementation (Solaris) chokes on this:

```
$ date | sed -E 's/0/x/g'
sed: illegal option -- E
```

Comment: But when I execute `sed -n -e '/^[0-9]{3}$/p' file.txt`, it print nothing ! "-E" is ok. I work in Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have old or unmaintained man/info pages? The command itself has it in the help and the source code repository has the option explained in the documentation also.

Comment: thanks, maybe there's something strange with my ubuntu, I'm using ubuntu 14.04